# sp_who2 'active' automating using Java

Tags: java, eclipse, jdbc, ssms

1. I'm trying to execute a query sp_who2 'active' using java in Microsoft SQL server management studio.
2. If the query executes successfully, it checks for blocking on the database and if any blocking is there, I shall get a email notification with the SPID that's causing the blocking.
3. So far, I'm trying to connect to the database like this :

   ```
   package database;

   import java.sql.Connection;
   import java.sql.DriverManager;

   public class Main {

   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       // TODO Auto-generated method stub

       getConnection();

   }
   public static Connection getConnection() throws Exception{

       try {
           String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
           String url = "jdbc:sqlserver://myLaptopName//SQLEXPRESS";
           String username = "myUserName";
           String password = "myPassword";
           Class.forName(driver).newInstance();

           Connection connect = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
           System.out.println(connect);
           System.out.println("Connected");

           return connect; 
       } catch (Exception e) {
           // TODO: handle exception
           System.out.println("something is wrong");
           e.printStackTrace();
       }

       return null;
   }

   }
   ```

   And the error I'm getting in the eclipse is this.

   `java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: Cannot load connection class 
    because of underlying exception:com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections`.

And this too.

`Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.WrongArgumentException: Malformed database URL, failed to parse the main URL sections.`

I know I'm doing something wrong, and that's what I intend to know. Any help would be appreciated. I'm trying but couldn't really find a solution that could resolve this. 
Any help would be appreciated guys!

Comment: remove a slash `/SQLEXPRESS` try `"jdbc:sqlserver://myLaptopName/SQLEXPRESS"`

Comment: Thanks @YCF_L. that cleared out the previous error. But now a new one, `java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:sqlserver:/myLaptopName/SQLEXPRESS` 
I have this jar configured as well mysql-connector-java-8.0.11

Comment: no don't remove the two slashes just the one before the database name try with this `"jdbc:sqlserver://myLaptopName/SQLEXPRESS"`

Comment: beside are you using sqlserver or mysql?

Comment: sqlserver . I have installed Microsoft sql server management studio and trying to connect to that using this.. Is it not the right approach?

Comment: try to follow this tutorial then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connection-url-sample?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Okay thanks. Will check this out. And will probably return if I'd need any help!